# Python invalid syntax for print("Hello, world!")

Tags: python, invalidation

I don't understand why I get the error for invalid syntax for my simple code print("Hello, world!")

I've installed Python in my pc. I'm running it on the cmd, changed my directory to the one where my file is at, but I still get an error.

Here is what my cmd says when I get the error:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1889]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\angel>cd C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documentos\html css course

C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documentos\html css course>py
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python hello.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hello.py
           ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're in the python shell, where the input is expected to be python syntax. Your script contains python syntax. Execute it with `python hello.py` _outside_ of the python shell (i.e., where you typed `py` before).

Comment: Note that, if you have been told to use the `py` command (which chooses the correct version), type `py hello.py`.

Comment: this is what I get now, Python was not found --- C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documentos\html css course>python hello.py Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Answer (score 0):

`python` should be the name of the Python executable - you should be calling it from your terminal **instead** of opening the Python interpreter. Having said that, it seems that the name of the executable you're using is `py`, not `python`:

```
C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documentos\html css course>py hello.py
```

Comment: this is what I get now, Python was not found --- C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documentos\html css course>python hello.py
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: @Angely it seems that the executable you're using is `py`, not `python`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. When I did this, my Git Bash directed me to my Microsoft Store to download Python. I had it downloaded from their website, but seems like I needed it installed via de Microsoft Store directly... This solved my problem, again thanks!